# Is it possible to use multiple ScreenManager widgets in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Well hi, just signed up for this question.
Ive started working with `Kivy` this week, so far so good, I guess. Im making some sort of `POS software`, so far I've done things separately, a folder for each module, dashboard(this one module has other modules, sales, providers, products, clients, reports, etc.), operator, and login. I have a `main.py` and `main.kv` on root folder, in `main.kv` I have a `ScreenManager` that opens the login form on start and then takes me to either operator or dashboard depending the user. Thing is dashboard has another `ScreenManager`, so i can switch between the other modules that it has in it, it works on standalone but when i call it on `main.py` withing main.kv it crashes, it doesn't seem to accept two ScreenManager widgets.

My goal is to:
[Apparently i cant post GIF yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3lY2.gif)

The dashboard works like the gif when I run the `dashboard.py` file alone but when invoked in `main.py` it crashes, to be able to run I've to remove the `ScreenManager` widget class from `dashboard.kv` and `ofc` the container that holds the screen widgets crashes it displays all the other modules at once.

I thought about using the add_widget method and threat the screen widgets like a regular box widget but figured that it would just spam the widget on every click like one on top of the other and i think using the clear_widget to remove the previous widget would be just too hard coded, plus I would loose the transition animation

Question is, how can i achieve mentioned goal?
sorry about the gif, it was a 5 mins blender thing.
also English, not main. :s

Comment: Pretty sure, it's possible. The cause of the issue probably is the other part of the code.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. If you want real help, you must post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for both replies. As mentioned I wasn't sure about multiple ScreenManager widgets and I was very frustrated that I couldn't find the issue, cause of your answers I went and double check the .kv files and found a Screen widget being inherited as BoxLayout in a deep .kv file and it was it. Thank you tho. Just removed the *@BoxLayout from it and it does now work.